# How to use and map alias string instead of id in UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, string, angular-ui-router, alias

Usually I use `ui-router` state with `id` parameter like this:

```
/* route /news/{news_id} */

http://servername/#‌​/news/14
```

but already I want to use `alias string` instead of `id` like this:

```
/* route /news/{news_title} */

http://servername/#‌​/news/braking-news-of-usa
```

How to map `news_title` to `news_id` in angular or ui-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this specific to Angular, but you can consider following approaches.

- Along with title append news id with some separator. e.g. breaking_news_of_usa_14. When someone clicks that link, in Javascript split the news title and retrieve the ID to query server API.
- Make sure you have unique titles for news (overhead at serverside API e.g. unique index, hashes etc.) and instead of querying with news id, query using news title to get the details.
- Maintain both news ID and news title like this /{news_title/{news_id}. With this you save overhead of introducing unique titles. (Reference, check stackoverflow URL format for question details.)